# The whole data I fetch is stored into the first index of the array

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, decodable

This is my structure

And this is the array than I want to be filled with 20 ids.

```
var news = [All]()
```

Here is the data of one id. I want to fetch first 20 id's info.

> ```
> {
>     "by": "jonbaer",
>     "descendants": 57,
>     "id": 20643604,
>     "kids": [
>         20643886,
>         20644273,
>         20644769,
>         20643937,
>         20643955,
>         20644451,
>         20643969,
>         20643915,
>         20643904,
>         20643858,
>         20644046
>     ],
>     "score": 242,
>     "time": 1565264884,
>     "title": "AMD lands Google, Twitter as customers with newest server chip",
>     "type": "story",
>     "url": "https://www.reuters.com/article/us-amd-alphabet/amd-lands-google-twitter-as-customers-with-newest-server-chip-idUSKCN1UX2KL"
> }
> ```

this my fetch function. I am taking an array of integers. I want to fetch first 20 id's data.

```
func fetchInfo(of Id: [Int], completion: @escaping 
(Result<All,Error>) -> Void){

    for i in 0..<20 {

    guard let url = URL(string: "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/\(Id[i]).json") else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

      if let error = error {
        completion(.failure(error))
        return
      }
      guard let jsonData = data else { return }
      do{

        let info = try JSONDecoder().decode(All.self, from: jsonData)

        completion(.success(info))

      }catch let error {
        completion(.failure(error))
      }

    }.resume()
    }
}
```

First I'm fetching the ids and storing them into an array then I pass the array of integers and trying to print but it does not work.

```
NetworkManager.shared.fetchIds { (result) in

      switch result {
      case .success(let id):
        self.users = id
          print("\(self.users) + \(self.users.count)")
        NetworkManager.shared.fetchInfo(of: self.users, completion: { (result) in
          switch result {
          case .success(let info):
            self.news = [info]
            self.news.forEach({ (item) in
              print(item.title + item.username)
            })
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
          case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
          }
        })
      case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
      }

  }
```

When I launched the application. my first cell is updated by 1 to 20 info. I want 20 cells and 20 info in sequence. 0 to 19.

Comment: the array is -> var news = [All]() , not var news = All

Comment: struct All: Decodable {
  
  let username: String
  let title: String
  let url: String
  
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case username = "by", title, url
  }
  
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each answer you get you create a new array and assign it to your `news` array but what you rather need to do is to *append* each answer

In the completion handler change

```
self.news = [info]
```

to

```
self.news.append(info)
```